# How to run Protractor test when spec is remote

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver, protractor

Here's the situation:

- machineA has Protractor, Selenium, WebDriver, etc. installed.
- machineB has all source code including tests and server running source code, but no Protractor, Selenium, etc
- environment is Linux on both machines

How can I run the Protractor command on machineA so that it points to the spec on machineB?

ie. How to get a local Protractor command to point to a remote spec?

Comment: You can use maven as a build tool .. or Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide seleniumAddress in your config file and make sure directConnect option is commented or value should be false.

Start webdriver on machineA through `webdriver-manager start`

```
exports.config = {
    baseUrl: 'http://example.com/',
    seleniumAddress: 'https://<machineA IP addess>:4444/wd/hub',
    //directConnect:true,
...
}
```

Comment: @yong, Anil, the exports.config is on machineB?  What's the protractor command to initiate the testing on machineB from machineA?  Remember, machineB does not have protractor, selenium, node, etc.  Machine A ONLY has the applications, but no protractor config or tests...they live on machineB.  Thanks!

Comment: @Anil, I forgot one thing,  you need to install protractor on machineB,  but no need to run webdriver on machineB (no need to execute webdriver-manager update and webdriver-manager start, but need to execute npm install protractor)

Comment: @yong, do you know if it's possible to run protractor remotely as well with the use of PyTest and Protractor module for Python? Like:

python -m pytest -m testProtractor   --selenium-hub=ic-vm-webdriver-01 -v -s --skip-extensions --suite=dashboard_gating,dashboard_automation --junitxml="system-tests.xml"

Comment: Actually, we need to have protractor installed in the machine where is your source code(Machine B in your case) and you need to have Selenium webdriver where you are running the the test cases(machine A).
having Protractor on Machine A is useless, we need this at machine B.